# Does running a script inside a script make the overall process slower?

Tags: bash, scripting

If I have a directory full of bash scripts and I create a script to run all of them consecutively, not concurrently, will it be significantly slower than if I had just run them all one at a time in terminal?

Comment: No, it won't be slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight insignificant overhead for that one additional script (kernel shebang processing, initialization of the bash interpreter, bash reading in the source, ...) but let's say that it is more than negligible and you can treat it as nonexistent.

No, you won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 3):

No it won't . practically, Using one file is faster than multiple files if you consider your human speed :) .

Use time command line with the two choices and confirm .

```
time Main.sh
```

and

```
time { script1.sh; script2.sh; scriptN.sh; }
```

Comment: Your second snippet should look more like `time { script1.sh; script2.sh; scriptN.sh; }`, otherwise the comparison is even less meaningful than it already is using `time` ;-)